# How to add other class to current stage - JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I have javafx application that show some info.

I am new to javafx and trying to understand things while trying some tests.

I want to add clock on top of the application, and i found [next source](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/2658491)

How can i add this clock (from the source) to my current application on same screen (on top of the screen)? my app use next code on `main.java` (i am using also FXML file and edit it by Scene builder):

```
package sample;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import net.sourceforge.zmanim.hebrewcalendar.JewishCalendar;
import net.sourceforge.zmanim.hebrewcalendar.HebrewDateFormatter;
import net.sourceforge.zmanim.hebrewcalendar.JewishCalendar;
import net.sourceforge.zmanim.util.GeoLocation;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        Label lblShabat = (Label) root.lookup("#shabat");
        Label lbldateHeb = (Label) root.lookup("#dateHeb");

        JewishCalendar israelCalendar = new JewishCalendar();
        israelCalendar.setInIsrael(true); //set the calendar to Israel
        JewishCalendar chutsLaaretzCalendar = new JewishCalendar();
        chutsLaaretzCalendar.setInIsrael(false); //not really needed since the API defaults to false
        JewishCalendar jd = new JewishCalendar();
        HebrewDateFormatter hdf = new HebrewDateFormatter();
        hdf.setHebrewFormat(true);

        for(int i = 0; i < 14; i++){
            israelCalendar.forward(); //roll the date forward a day
            //  chutsLaaretzCalendar.forward(); //roll the date forward a day
            if(israelCalendar.getDayOfWeek() == 7){ //ignore weekdays
                if (lblShabat!=null) lblShabat.setText(hdf.formatYomTov(jd)); //hdf.formatParsha(israelCalendar)
                //hdf.formatYomTov(jd)
            }
        }
        String cholHamoedSuccos = "חול המועד סוכות";
        if(hdf.formatYomTov(jd) == cholHamoedSuccos) {
            String image = Main.class.getResource("Dollarphotoclub_91486993.jpg").toExternalForm();
            root.setStyle("-fx-background-image: url('" + image + "'); " +
                    "-fx-background-position: center center; " +
                    "-fx-background-repeat: stretch;");

        }
        if (lbldateHeb!=null) lbldateHeb.setText(hdf.format(jd));

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
        primaryStage.setFullScreen(true);
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is perhaps a better way that doesn't require as much refactoring, but I refactored Clock so a function createLayout() is separated from the start() function of Clock. In SceneBuilder add a subscene where you want the clock placed and set an id for it, I used `clocksubscene`. In the controller initialize() function create the layout and set the root of clocksubscene to layout. Also added the clock.css to the styles of main scene.

Refactored Clock.java (ommitted parts were unchanged) :

```
public void start(final Stage stage) throws Exception {

    Parent layout = createLayout();
    final Scene scene = new Scene(layout, Color.TRANSPARENT);
    scene.getStylesheets().add(getResource("clock.css"));

    // show the scene.
    stage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}

public Parent createLayout() {
    // construct the analogueClock pieces.
    final Circle face = new Circle(100, 100, 100);
    face.setId("face");
    final Label brand = new Label("Splotch");
    brand.setId("brand");
    brand.layoutXProperty().bind(face.centerXProperty().subtract(brand.widthProperty().divide(2)));
    brand.layoutYProperty().bind(face.centerYProperty().add(face.radiusProperty().divide(2)));
    final Line hourHand = new Line(0, 0, 0, -50);
    hourHand.setTranslateX(100);
    hourHand.setTranslateY(100);
    hourHand.setId("hourHand");
    final Line minuteHand = new Line(0, 0, 0, -75);
    minuteHand.setTranslateX(100);
    minuteHand.setTranslateY(100);
    minuteHand.setId("minuteHand");
    final Line secondHand = new Line(0, 15, 0, -88);
    secondHand.setTranslateX(100);
    secondHand.setTranslateY(100);
    secondHand.setId("secondHand");
    final Circle spindle = new Circle(100, 100, 5);
    spindle.setId("spindle");
    Group ticks = new Group();
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        Line tick = new Line(0, -83, 0, -93);
        tick.setTranslateX(100);
        tick.setTranslateY(100);
        tick.getStyleClass().add("tick");
        tick.getTransforms().add(new Rotate(i * (360 / 12)));
        ticks.getChildren().add(tick);
    }
    final Group analogueClock = new Group(face, brand, ticks, spindle, hourHand, minuteHand, secondHand);

    // construct the digitalClock pieces.
    final Label digitalClock = new Label();
    digitalClock.setId("digitalClock");

    // determine the starting time.
    Calendar calendar = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
    final double seedSecondDegrees = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND) * (360 / 60);
    final double seedMinuteDegrees = (calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + seedSecondDegrees / 360.0) * (360 / 60);
    final double seedHourDegrees = (calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR) + seedMinuteDegrees / 360.0) * (360 / 12);

    // define rotations to map the analogueClock to the current time.
    final Rotate hourRotate = new Rotate(seedHourDegrees);
    final Rotate minuteRotate = new Rotate(seedMinuteDegrees);
    final Rotate secondRotate = new Rotate(seedSecondDegrees);
    hourHand.getTransforms().add(hourRotate);
    minuteHand.getTransforms().add(minuteRotate);
    secondHand.getTransforms().add(secondRotate);

    // the hour hand rotates twice a day.
    final Timeline hourTime = new Timeline(
            new KeyFrame(
                    Duration.hours(12),
                    new KeyValue(
                            hourRotate.angleProperty(),
                            360 + seedHourDegrees,
                            Interpolator.LINEAR
                    )
            )
    );

    // the minute hand rotates once an hour.
    final Timeline minuteTime = new Timeline(
            new KeyFrame(
                    Duration.minutes(60),
                    new KeyValue(
                            minuteRotate.angleProperty(),
                            360 + seedMinuteDegrees,
                            Interpolator.LINEAR
                    )
            )
    );

    // move second hand rotates once a minute.
    final Timeline secondTime = new Timeline(
            new KeyFrame(
                    Duration.seconds(60),
                    new KeyValue(
                            secondRotate.angleProperty(),
                            360 + seedSecondDegrees,
                            Interpolator.LINEAR
                    )
            )
    );

    // the digital clock updates once a second.
    final Timeline digitalTime = new Timeline(
            new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(0),
                    new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                        @Override
                        public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                            Calendar calendar = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
                            String hourString = pad(2, '0', calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR) == 0 ? "12" : calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR) + "");
                            String minuteString = pad(2, '0', calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + "");
                            String secondString = pad(2, '0', calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND) + "");
                            String ampmString = calendar.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == Calendar.AM ? "AM" : "PM";
                            digitalClock.setText(hourString + ":" + minuteString + ":" + secondString + " " + ampmString);
                        }
                    }
            ),
            new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1))
    );

    // time never ends.
    hourTime.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
    minuteTime.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
    secondTime.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
    digitalTime.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);

    // start the analogueClock.
    digitalTime.play();
    secondTime.play();
    minuteTime.play();
    hourTime.play();



    // add a glow effect whenever the mouse is positioned over the clock.
    final Glow glow = new Glow();
    analogueClock.setOnMouseEntered(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
            analogueClock.setEffect(glow);
        }
    });
    analogueClock.setOnMouseExited(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
            analogueClock.setEffect(null);
        }
    });

    // layout the scene.
    final VBox layout = new VBox();
    layout.getChildren().addAll(analogueClock, digitalClock);
    layout.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    return layout;
}
```

new Controller initialize code:

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    Clock clock = new Clock();
    clocksubscene.setRoot(clock.createLayout());
}
```

In main start routine:

```
 Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 275);
 scene.getStylesheets().add(Clock.getResource("clock.css"));
 primaryStage.setScene(scene);
```

Comment: I would go one step further and refactor it so that the `createLayout()` method is in a separate class, that is not an `Application` subclass. (I'd probably call that class `Clock` and the original `Application` subclass `ClockApp`.) That way you don't need the excess API of the `Application` and `start(...)` method, etc etc, if you're not using it.

Answer (score 1):

```
TheStageOfthesource.getScene().getRoot();//will give you the root pane
```

*is that what you want* ? then you add it to your `Pane`

Comment: I think you might find that doesn't work as easily as you think it does if you actually try it... First, you can't have one node in two different scenes (you get an exception, I think). And second, how do you get access to that `Stage` in the first place?

Comment: funny right @James_D  just being cute :) im deleting it though